# Search For library in maven repository is not working

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jfoenix

Hello Guys please I need a little bit of help, I am trying to download the jfoenix library from the maven repository in intellij but when I add the "jfoenix" keyword to the search box, it Doesn't work! But when I add the keyword "spring" it works. Please help me thanks

Comment: Please add more information about your search requests.

Comment: Please try "com.jfoenix". Looks related to this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259931